# text to dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, text

I have a problem in making a dataframe with a text in R.
my text is like this:

```
t1 = "[[1,5,3,4],[3,2,2,1],[19,11,1,1]]"
```

and I want to make this dataframe:

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4
  1  1  5  3  4
  2  3  2  2  1
  3 19 11  1  1
```

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON(t1)`

Comment: wow thank you it works well! @DavidArenburg <3

Comment: notice result is not a dataframe; it is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the comments, you need to do:

```
yourDf <- as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(t1))
```